# Default excluding condition and extension to include them back

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a repository attached to some data source. It has a method `GetAll()` that return queryable list and extension to filter this data.

```
public class Repository {
    int[] dataSource = new[] {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1};

    public IQueryable<int> GetAll()
    {
        return dataSource.AsQueryable();
    }
}

public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static IQueryable<int> WithoutZero(this IQueryable<int> list)
    {
        return list.Where(x => x != 0);
    }
}
```

I want to setup default condition on repository to not read `0` values by default. Moreover I want to have extension method to enable reading also `0` values.

```
public class Repository {
    int[] dataSource = new[] {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1};

    public IQueryable<int> GetAll()
    {
        return dataSource.AsQueryable().Where(x => x != 0);
    }
}

public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static IQueryable<int> WithZero(this IQueryable<int> list)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I know that I can do this using default parameter on `GetAll()` method like:

```
public IQueryable<int> GetAll(bool readZeros = false)
{
    if (readZeros)
    {
        return dataSource.AsQueryable();
    } else {
        return dataSource.AsQueryable().Where(x => x != 0);
    }
}
```

But I wonder how can I do this using extension methods and `Queryable<>` collections?

For example in `Repository` by default I want to return only not deleted records but with extension method I want to show both deleted and not deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to create criteria class like this:

```
  public class ItemsCriteria {
      public bool RemoveZeroes {get;set;}
  }
```

Then, use it in your repository class:

```
    public IQueryable<int> GetItems(ItemsCriteria  criteria)
    {
        var q = GetAllDataQueryable();
        if (criteria.RemoveZeroes) q = q.Where(x => x != null)
        return q;
    }
```

Advantages:

- Easy to add/remove criterias
- Easy to turn on/off criterias <- you need this
- Criteria class can support large number of rules

Comment: Thanks, it is good and flexible addition to mentioned by me solution with default values, but his is not exactly what I want. it requires too many refactoring in existed code.

Comment: I know you asked about extension method, but, it is close and now I have +2 points. Good luck and I hope you will refactor, it is always good way

Comment: I have another idea: you can create your own IQueryable<T> class which holds original IQueryable<T> with additional field "bool removeZeroes". Your own class will works as proxy and a criteria class. So, there will be no reason to change legacy. But, of course this is a hack and better to refactor

Comment: I would choose your solution if I would write this from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Not a very generic solution, but you can return the original data source of your query and that would effectively let you start querying from scratch again:

```
public static IQueryable<int> WithZeros(this IQueryable<int> list)
{
    var expr = list.Expression as MethodCallExpression;
    var constantExpr = expr.Arguments.OfType<ConstantExpression>().First(x => x.Value is IEnumerable<int>);
    var origDataSource = constantExpr.Value as IEnumerable<int>;

    return origDataSource.AsQueryable();
}
```

The better option would be to update the expression trees, but that's beyond me.